# Why changes done to variables reflect in List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Changes done in start variable and end variable are reflected in fli list. What is the reason behind that?

```
flight = (input("Enter arrival time and departure time of flight : ").split())
fl=[]
while flight != []:
    fl.append(flight)
    flight = (input("Enter arrival time and departure time of flight : ").split())
fl = sorted(fl)
fli= []
for i in fl:
    f = []
    f.append(list(map(int,i[0].split(":"))))
    f.append(list(map(int, i[1].split(":"))))
    fli.append(f)

runway = 0
max_runway = 0
fli = sorted(fli)
arrival = []
departure = []
for i in fli:
    arrival.append(i[0])
    departure.append(i[1])

start = fli[0][0]
max_time = start
for i in fli:
    for j in i:
        if j > max_time:
            max_time = j
end = max_time
end[1] += 1
if end[1] % 60 == 0:
    end[0] += 1
    end[1] = 0
if end[0] % 24 == 0:
    end[0] = 0

while start != end:
    if start in arrival:
        runway += 1
    if start in departure:
        runway -= 1
    if max_runway < runway:
        max_runway = runway
    start[1] += 1
    if start[1] % 60 == 0:
        start[0] += 1
        start[1] = 0
    if start[0] % 24 == 0:
        start[0] = 0
print(max_runway)
```

fli list before while loop is : `[[[9, 15], [9, 25]], [[9, 20], [9, 45]], [[9, 30], [9, 35]], [[9, 30], [9, 38]], [[9, 35], [9, 40]]]`

fli list after while loop is : `[[[9, 46], [9, 25]], [[9, 20], [9, 46]], [[9, 30], [9, 35]], [[9, 30], [9, 38]], [[9, 35], [9, 40]]]`

Comment: It would be helpful if sample input is added

Comment: Because some Python objects are mutable. If you edit the variables themselves, the changes will reflect elsewhere. Here, start refers to an element in `fli`, not a copy of that element, so incrementing the values in it will change the values in `fli` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a = [4,9]**, a is an object in python, and when you assign an object to a variable i.e. **b = a**, then a new object is not created **b** point to the same object(memory location) as **a**.

See the following execution for a better understanding.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thnkew so much.

Answer (score 0):

- `fli[0][0]` is a list not a scalar
- `start  = fli[0][0]`  : `start` points to the same list which is at `fli[0][0]`. Any changes done on  `start` is same as doing it `fli[0][0]`

Test

```
fli = [[[9, 15], [9, 25]], [[9, 20], [9, 45]], [[9, 30], [9, 35]], [[9, 30], [9, 38]], [[9, 35], [9, 40]]]
a = fli[0][0]
a[1] += 1
assert fli[0][0][1] == a[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python objects like list, set and dict are mutable. Meaning you can change their content without changing their identity. The case here looks similar. Basically, start is referring fli. So making any changes to start will also change the values in fli.